# Win form application freeze on HttpWebRequest file post

Tags: asp.net, winforms, httpwebrequest

I have an application that will upload files from my client to a web server using HttpWebRequest (with the function suggested here: [Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data))

My problem is that when the file (about 10 mb in size) is being posted the whole application freezes (e.g. "application is not responding" when I try to move the window).

Do I need to put the uploading in a separate thread, or is there any other simple way solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class. Your UI will freeze while an operation is ongoing unless you run it in a separate thread.

Using the `BackgroundWorker` you can execute your code in the `DoWork` event and the UI will remain responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Multithreaded programming is the way to go in this case.

You can create a delegate for a function that will upload the file and use BeginInvoke to execute the function in a seperate thread.

Or you could simply create a new thread by using the Thread class and the build-in .net ThreadPool.